# Concat arrays with javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist, concatenation

How I concat arrays if I have "i" number of arrays

var i = numberOfarrays;

so now I have to do something like that:

```
bigArray = row[0].concat(row[1]).concat(row[2])... ...concat(row[i]);
```

How I can concat i number of arrays?

Comment: do you want to store all elemnents in a main array??

Comment: yes to stor all arrays ibto one big

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this :

```
var bigArray = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], row)
```

which can be reduced to

```
var bigArray = [].concat.apply([], row)
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qGVJe/

Comment: +1 I've just deleted my post with exactly the same solution, you posted it 50 secs earlier :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qGVJe/1/)**

```
var row = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
var bigArray=[];
for(i=0;i<row.length;i++)
   bigArray= bigArray.concat(row[i]);
```

Comment: You should try... concat doesn't work like you think it works.

Comment: It still seems unnecessary to use `concat` like this. What you're after is `push`. `concat` shouldn't need to be used like this in an loop, especially because it creates/returns a **new** array every `concat` call

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

```
var a = ['1','2','3'];    
var b = ['4','5','6'];
var final_array = a.concat(b); 
//console.log shows final_array is now an an array with: ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
```

Apply:

```
bigArray=[];
for(i=0;i<small_array.length;i++){
    bigArray.concat(small_array[i]);
    }
or
 for(i=0;i<small_array.length;i++){
    bigArray.push(small_array[i]);
    }
```